# How do you convert this SQL query from String to Int?

Tags: java, derby

How do you convert this SQL query from String to Int ?

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM DEMO.QUESTION " +
      "WHERE CAST (QUESTION_ID = '"+question+"' ,INT(10))";
```

Comment: Well, it is nice to smile ... indeed.

Comment: Specifically what are you trying to do!? assuming you are using MySQL, that would be either 0 or 1... but (at least for me) that does not make any sense! You could delete only the matchig values and go on!

Comment: Or... are you trying to cast the `question` variable as an `int` and perform the delete after that? What should happen if `question` is not a valid `int`-like string?

Comment: yup, I want to do that

Comment: by the way, besides using derby as your database, which language are you programming on?

Comment: I'm using Java Servlet

Comment: So, is that correct the way I convert the data type in my SQL query?

Comment: Your SQL query is a `String`!!!!! What you want to convert is the parameter of your `where` clause!

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question: You are trying to perform a `cast` operation on a boolean value, which I don't think is what you want (and it's irrelevant anyway).

So, I think that what you are trying to do is this:

```
sql = "delete from demo.question " + 
      "where QUESTION_ID = cast('" + question + "', int)"
```

Some comments on this:

1. Your question variable can be parsed to an integer value in your code before passing it to the query... that would remove the need for your `cast` function.
2. What would you do if your `question` variable holds the value `"abc"`? Consider that scenario.
3. Your query is quite vulnerable to SQL Injection attacs. Consider using prepared statements.

---

***Update***

Since you are using Java, and reinforcing my third observation, you should take a look to [the Java tutorial on the topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) (and also to [this](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/Derby-PreparedStatement.html)).

I insist, instead of passing a string and casting it in your query, parse it in your Java code as an integer and free yourself of your problem.